# Find all distinct combinations recursion python

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, combinations

I am trying to find all the distinct combinations in X (e.g X={1,2,3}) where the numbers add up to N using brute force approach.

```
def findSum(my_str):
    total_sum = 0
    for ch in my_str:
        total_sum += int(ch)
    return total_sum
```

```
def combination_sum(my_list,my_str,X,N,count):
    if count == int(N/X[0]) + 1: # set maximum depth
        return

    if findSum(my_str) == N: # see if numbers add up to N
        my_list.append(copy.deepcopy(my_str)) 
        return

    for i in X: # do nested forloop
        combination_sum(my_list,my_str + str(i),X,N, count+1)
```

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = 5
    X = [1,2,3]
    X.sort() # sort in increasing order
    my_str = ''
    my_list = []

    combination_sum(my_list,my_str,X,N,count=0)
    print(my_list)
```

Here I use my_str to store all possible combinations, but I want to use a list instead of string because it has sum() function. Then I wouldn't need to implement findSum(). But when I do so, the list keeps getting larger and larger with each append(i) inside the forloop. How can I achieve the same result using list?

Comment: I you use a list instead of a str, and write `my_lst + [i]` instead of `my_str + str(i)`, there shouldn't be any issue. `my_lst + [i]` builds a new list without modifying the old list, whereas `my_lst.append(i)` modifies `my_lst`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to remember to delete appended value in cycle before the next cycle iteration to prevent the list growth and keep the logic correct.

With strings you pass modified version of my_str `my_str + str(i)`, keeping my_str intact. So with list to keep it intact - just reverse the changes each time using `pop()`.

I changed your code to work with lists. I had to rename `my_str` and `my_list` to `current_combination` and `all_combinations`, otherwise I confused those.

```
import copy

def combination_sum(all_combinations, current_combination, X, N, count):
    if count == int(N / X[0]) + 1: # set maximum depth
        return

    if sum(current_combination) == N: # see if numbers add up to N
        all_combinations.append(copy.deepcopy(current_combination)) 
        return

    for i in X: # do nested forloop
        current_combination.append(i)
        combination_sum(all_combinations, current_combination, X, N, count + 1)
        # reverse the changes!
        current_combination.pop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = 5
    X = [1,2,3]
    X.sort() # sort in increasing order
    current_combination = []
    all_combinations = []

    combination_sum(all_combinations, current_combination, X, N, count=0)
    print(all_combinations)
```